# How to debug code in Tizen browser in Samsung Smart TV

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing a simple web app which is supposed to work in Tizen Browser of a Samsung Smart TV (Model Year : 2016). I have got it to work in most major browsers like IE, edge, chrome, firefox, safari and opera in Mobile, Tablet and Desktop devices. But could not get it to work on Tizen (the smart TV browser)

Debugging the code has always been an irksome guessing game in the tizen browser.

Is there a developer tool bar like the one in Chrome for Tizen or can I be suggested with an easier way of debugging code in the Tizen browser?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio this maybe what you are looking for? Or https://developer.tizen.org/development/visual-studio-tools-tizen/installing-visual-studio-tools-tizen

Comment: thanks David. Guess thats the only way available to try and solve this. I did download a Tizen TV Emulator which amounted to about a giga byte and quarter. Seems like I still need to download Tizen studio to use the emulator in the first place. Grrrr

Comment: Technically I think it may be possible to use the Emulator Manager standalone and then enter the URL to your package into it. However I do advise against that, because there are enough issues with the emulator as it is. You can also deploy to the display and look into Weinre.

Comment: Any progress on this? I have an extremely hard time trying to get tizen studio etc working on recent macOS because of tizen requiring some very old specific java versions and still nothing really works...